# Auth Laravel 5.2 Route

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

There is quite a major change between laravel 5.2 from 5.1

My side doesnt redirect to the auth page when the page was trying to be directly accessed.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::get('projects', 'ProjectController@index');
    Route::post('projects', 'ProjectController@create');


    Route::get('todo', 'ToDoController@index');
    Route::post('todo', 'ToDoController@create');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `auth` middleware to your route

```
Route::get('projects', 'ProjectController@index')->middleware(['auth']);
```

Or you can add middleware in your controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```